# How to run end-to-end spring-batch test using maven?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-batch, integration-testing

I did my integration test of spring-batch without problem. I followed the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/3.0.x/reference/html/testing.html). My test needs a property file to execute. It execute ok (Crt + F11), green :D. No error in an individual execution.

My problem happen when I try to execute all the application using maven (clean install) without skip the test. I need to do this because it is what will happen on Jenkins.

I add System.out.println("....") to track that inside the "beforeClass", "before", "constructor" and  "launchJob" methods. It's printed only in beforeClass and in the constructor.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:jobs/myJob.xml"} )
public class MyIntegrationTest {

@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {
  System.out.println("############# BEFORE CLASS ");
  System.setProperty("propertyfile",  "classpath:test.properties");
}

public MyIntegrationTest() {
   System.out.println("############# CONSTRUCTOR ");
}

@Autowired
private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

private JdbcTemplate  jdbcTemplate;

@Before
public void before() {
   System.out.println("############# BEFORE");
   ...
}

@Test
public void launchJob() throws Exception {
   System.out.println("############# LAUNCHJOB");
   JobExecution step = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
   Assert.assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, step.getStatus());
}
```

It should be worked like the isolated execution but throws exception:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running MyTestIntegration
2019-07-04 14:38:18,935 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:myJob.xml]
2019-07-04 14:38:19,359 [main] INFO  o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
2019-07-04 14:38:19,403 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'myJob': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.SimpleFlowFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.JobParserJobFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2019-07-04 14:38:19,409 [main] INFO  o.s.c.support.GenericApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@c46bcd4: startup date [Thu Jul 04 14:38:19 BST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-07-04 14:38:19,555 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@57250572] to prepare test instance [MyIntegrationTest@5609159b]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157) ~[spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109) ~[spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75) ~[spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:313) ~[spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211) [spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288) [spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284) [spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231) [spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88) [spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71) [spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236) [junit-4.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174) [spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264) [surefire-junit4-2.14.jar:2.14]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153) [surefire-junit4-2.14.jar:2.14]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124) [surefire-junit4-2.14.jar:2.14]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208) [surefire-api-2.14.jar:2.14]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:158) [surefire-booter-2.14.jar:2.14]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86) [surefire-booter-2.14.jar:2.14]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153) [surefire-booter-2.14.jar:2.14]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95) [surefire-booter-2.14.jar:2.14]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52) ~[spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80) ~[spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102) ~[spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76) ~[spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461) ~[spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:106) ~[spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:57) ~[spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100) ~[spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248) ~[spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124) ~[spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148) ~[spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.178 sec <<< FAILURE!
launchJob(MyIntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 0.761 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:106)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:57)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:313)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)


Results :

Tests in error: 
   » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.775 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-04T14:38:19+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 59M/758M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14:test (integration-tests) on project kappa-batch: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\...\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

In the first moment I was thinking that it could be related with the propertyFile. But I put that explicitly in the code but it was the same result,  it worked with isolated unit test (ctr + F11) and it didn't work with maven (clean install).

I tried add plugins and new configs in pom.xml, did put the property file in pom, but these didn't make difference.

PS: My configurations is using xml. The datasource to test is h2database

```
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>
```

And in my property file is:

```
jdbc.driver=org.h2.Driver
jdbc.user=sa
jdbc.password=
jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:dbtest/myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: That is strange, it is failing to initialize the context. Can you add the full exception stacktrace?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Hi. I updated the question with the full stack and with the datasource

Comment: Is your property file under `src/test/resources` or `src/main/resources` ? For tests, it should be in `src/test/resources`.

Comment: Hi: Yes. To guarantee I put inside the two folders. And it is configurated in pom.xml